# Excel VBA still breaks after On Error handler

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very simple bit of code that loops through a column of data and adds unique values to a Collection.

It's VBA, so of course `Collection` lacks an `Exists` function (who'd ever want that?), and I'd rather avoid iterating over the entire collection for every cell in the column, I decided to go for the error-handling approach - attempt to retrieve the item from the collection, catch the error that occurs if it doesn't exist and add it:

```
'Trucated the code slightly, I know I should be checking the actual error code, but omitted that for brevity

Dim r As Range
Set r = MySheet.Range("B2") 'First cell in column

Dim uniqueValues As New Collection
Do While r.Value <> ""
    On Error GoTo ItemExists
    'If r.Value doesn't exist in the collection, throws an error
    uniqueValues.Add(Item:=r.Value, Key:=r.Value) 
ItemExists:
    r.Offset(1)
Loop
```

The problem? Excel seems to be completely ignoring the `On Error` line, breaking the code and throws up the `Continue`/`End`/`Debug` dialog *regardless*.

I've checked the options in VBA, it's correctly set to `Break on Unhandled Errors.`

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Go with a `Dictionary` instead of `Collection`

Comment: Where will I find Dictionary? It doesn't seem to be part of the standard libraries.

Comment: Add references to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` or `CreateObject("Scirpting.Dictionary")`

Comment: Or use `On Error Resume Next` since that's basically what you're doing anyway. Also have a read up on error handling and the need for `Resume` statements.

Comment: You might be interested in [this attempt at building a better collection](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60504/building-a-better-collection-enumerable-in-vba). The whole project can now be found on [Github](https://github.com/ckuhn203/VBEX). (Oh, and please don't use `On Error Resume Next` unless you really understand what it does.)

Comment: @Rory, Ahhh! Don't encourage `On Error Resume Next`  :)

Comment: Yep, fully aware of the horrors of `On Error Resume Next`. Cheers :)

Comment: @bp_ In this context there is absolutely no problem with OERN. It may be oft misused, but that doesn't mean there's no place for it! ;)

Comment: And on the off chance you're on a Mac, you can't use the `Scripting.Dictionary` - you'll need your own class. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use On Error Resume Next, but you're better off encapsulating the error handling in its own Sub or Function.  E.g. something like:

```
Private Sub AddIfNotPresent(Coll As Collection, Value As Variant, Key As Variant)
    On Error Resume Next
    Coll.Add Item:=Value, Key:=Key
End Sub
```

which you could use as follows:

```
Do While r.Value <> ""
    AddIfNotPresent uniqueValues, r.Value, r.Value
    r = r.Offset(1)
Loop
```

The reason for your problem is described in the VBA documentation for `On Error`:

> An "enabled" error handler is one that is turned on by an On Error statement; an "active" error handler is an enabled handler that is in the process of handling an error. If an error occurs while an error handler is active (between the occurrence of the error and a Resume, Exit Sub, Exit Function, or Exit Property statement), the current procedure's error handler can't handle the error

You have not called Resume or exited the procedure after the first error, so the error handler can't handle subsequent errors.

**UPDATE**

From comments:

> I hate the idea of promoting the use of On Error Resume Next ...

I can sympathise with this POV, but there are some things in VBA (e.g. checking if a key is present in a Collection) that you can only do by handling an error.  If you do this in a dedicated helper method (Sub/Function), it's a reasonable approach.  Of course, you can use On Error Goto instead, e.g. something like the following (a variation on the above which tests to see if a collection contains a given key):

```
Public Function ContainsKey(Coll As Collection, Key As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim v As Variant
    v = Coll(Key)
    ContainsKey = True
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    ContainsKey = False
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: Although I hate the idea of promoting the use of `On Error Resume Next` this answer is correct in the sense that the OP did not `Resume` within the error handler.  It pains me to upvote this...

Comment: Just for added info for future Googlers; one of my favorite Err Handling sources: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

Comment: This is more-or-less what I ended up doing (though later changed to @vba4all's suggestion of using a Dictionary to avoid the error-handling thing altogether). Cheers~

Answer (score 1):

use an ArrayList instead, which has an .Contains method amongst other handy things like a .Sort method

```
With CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    .Add "Item 1"
    .Add "Item 2"

If .Contains "Item 1" Then Msgbox "Found Item 1"
If .Contains "Item 3" Then Msgbox "Found Item 3"


End With
```

some more examples [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=167349)